# What is the name of the derivative of Hessian matrix (a third order tensor)?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Is there a dedicated name for the derivative of `Hessian` matrix?

Suppose we have a multivariable scalar function function $f(\vec x) \in \mathbb R$ where $\vec x \in \mathbb R^n$, Its Hessian matrix is a $n \times n$ matrix, $\nabla_{x}^2 f \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$.

How about the name of its next derivative, $\nabla^3 f \in \mathbb R^{n \times n \times n}$? Or is there any related analysis about it?

Such a tensor is very useful when analysing the nonlinearity of is hessian matrix.